# XSD Element Not Null or Empty Constraint when other Element has a specific value

Tags: xml, xsd

HI All I am using XSD Version 1.0.
I have two Elements

```
<Manufacturer/>
<LocationCode/>
```

My XSD validation for location code is

```
<xs:element name="LocationCode" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
  <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:minLength value="1"/>
     </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

At the moment my xsd validates that location code is not null or empty. But I only want this validation to take effect if the Manufacturer is set to "APPLE" as shown here

```
<Manufacturer>APPLE</Manufacturer>
<LocationCode>232<LocationCode>
```

If the Manufacturer is something else then location can be empty

```
<Manufacturer>Microsoft</Manufacturer>
<LocationCode/>
```

I have searched the web and all I have found is that this can only be done with xsd version 1.1. But surely there must be a way around it for the example I have given above for version 1.0?

Comment: So you've already investigated and determined that this is possible with XSD v1.1, but not v1.0, but you don't want to use v1.1 for some reason? Why even bother posting this question at all? You've found your answer: and that is to use XSD v1.1.

Answer (score 1):

"Surely there must...?" Why? XSD 1.1 would not have been invented if it weren't for restrictions in XSD 1.0.

This cannot be done in XSD 1.0. If you haven't got access to an XSD 1.1 processor, the usual workaround is to add a second validation step using Schematron.